# Struts2.5 Get Struts Constant From struts.xml For Custom Result

Tags: java, struts2

I have written a custom result for Struts2 and would like to know the proper way to access the `<constants>` in the struts.xml?  I have tried to search the documentation for Struts and have come up empty so far.

I have tried to find the page on Struts docs for writing a custom result type, but I have not been able to locate it.  Here is the page on result types in general, but it is really of no help with what I am trying to achieve.

https://struts.apache.org/docs/result-types.html

Comment: That all fine and well but doing a search using the terms about injecting the struts 2 constant rendered nothing here. The title of the suggested duplicate "How to change default JSP/template location with Struts2" really had nothing to do with the question even though the end result of the question ended up using the @inject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inject it with `com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Inject` annotation.

In your custom result:

```
@Inject(value = "custom.const.some")
private String some;
```

In struts.xml:

```
<constant name="custom.const.some" value="constant_for_custom_result" />
```